# How do I do formulas with variables based on questions asked the users

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get the error "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'" in line 5 which is the "number = str(c(c*r)**x)" this is a weak attempt at making a growth calculator. Any help would be appriciated I am fairly new

```
import math
c = raw_input("what is the intial number?")
r = raw_input("What is the rate of growth?")
x = raw_input("How many years are taking place?")
int(c)
int(r)
int(x)
number = str(c(c*r)**x)
print (number)
```

Comment: c, r, x are strings to convert it you have to do `c =int(c)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to do in the same statement only, like this (user friendly way).

```
import math

c = int(raw_input("what is the intial number?\n=> "))
r = int(raw_input("What is the rate of growth?\n=> "))
x = int(raw_input("How many years are taking place?\n=> "))

number = str(c*(c*r)**x)
print(number)
```

> Output

```
what is the intial number?
=> 3
What is the rate of growth?
=> 4
How many years are taking place?
=> 5
746496
```

Comment: Okay, Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reassign the variables:

```
import math
c = raw_input("what is the intial number?")
r = raw_input("What is the rate of growth?")
x = raw_input("How many years are taking place?")
c = int(c)
r = int(r)
x = int(x)
number = str(c*(c*r)**x)
print (number)
```

Comment: You missed the `c(c*r)` bit. `c` is not a callable

Answer (score 0):

`int()` returns the parsed integer. You also need to put `*` for each multiplication operation you're doing.

`print` can print integers by default, no need for the `str` around `number`

```
import math
c = raw_input("what is the intial number?")
r = raw_input("What is the rate of growth?")
x = raw_input("How many years are taking place?")
c = int(c)
r = int(r)
x = int(x)
number = (c * (c * r))  ** x
print(number)
```